# How to store multiple document.referer value in sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to store multiple document.referer value in sessionStorage?

For example:

you visit *www.stackoverflow.com*

**->** current sessionStorage (value) is `www.stackoverflow.com` using JS **document.referer**

**->** then you click one of the link on stackoverflow.com, example you click stackoverflow questions 
page *www.stackoverflow.com/questions*. your current sessionStorage is now `www.stackoverflow.com/questions`

**->** and then you click one of the individual questions link `www.stackoverflow.com/questions/howtofixthis/`

How do we store the previous document.referer values in sessionStorage which is accessable in the fourth page 
example in `stackoverflow.com/questions/howtofixthis/` you click one users with link `www.stackoverflow.com/user/iamcoder`
in current page the previous the sessionStorage values should be accessable, the values are:

1st origin value = `www.stackoverflow.com`

2nd `www.stackoverflow.com/questions`

3rd `www.stackoverflow.com/questions.com/howtofixthis/`

4th `www.stackoverflow.com/user/iamcoder`

The purpose of using sessionStorage is to store visited pages url in current session and accessible through multiple external pages.

So far this I came up this code but doesn't store previous links at origin.

```
<script>
var s_origin = document.referrer;
var on_session = sessionStorage.setItem('origin', s_origin)
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('origin');
console.log('session origin ' + data)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the current value in session storage and append the new one.

```
function appendReferrer(value){

   if(value){

      var referrers = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('origin') || null) || [];
      referrers.push(value);
      sessionStorage.setItem('origin',JSON.stringify(referrers));

   }

}


function getReferrers(){

 return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('origin')) || [];

}
```

Usage:

```
//Append a new Item
appendReferrer("stackoverflow.com");

//Read all referrers
var referrers = getReferrers();
console.log(referrers);
```